# Explanation on destructuring

Tags: javascript

On codewars, there is the following question:

> ***Description***:
>
> *The Western Suburbs Croquet Club has two categories of membership, Senior and Open. They would like your help with an application form that will tell prospective members which category they will be placed.*
>
> *To be a senior, a member must be at least 55 years old and have a handicap greater than 7. In this croquet club, handicaps range from -2 to +26; the better the player the lower the handicap.*
>
> ***Input***
>
> *Input will consist of a list of lists containing two items each. Each list contains information for a single potential member. Information consists of an integer for the person's age and an integer for the person's handicap.*
>
> ***Example Input***
>
> [[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
>
> ***Output***
>
> *Output will consist of a list of string values (in Haskell: Open or Senior) stating whether the respective member is to be placed in the senior or open category.*
>
> ***Example Output***
>
> ["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]

One answer was beautiful in its simplicity:

```
function openOrSenior(data) {
    return data.map(([age, handicap]) => (age > 54 && handicap > 7) ? 'Senior' : 'Open');
}
```

It makes use of destructuring, and although I have read up on it, I have not a real good grasp of how this works. So here's the question: what is happening here? How does this work (in simplest terms possible)?

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Comment: The parameter is assumed to be a tuple (two-element array), the first element of which is assigned to `age`, and the second element to `handicap`.

Comment: What is unclear how exactly it is mapping it to age and handicap. What is it doing? Map takes a function, so in essence we have function([age, handicap]) { } passed to the map function. map acts on the data array, for each element, which is an array in itself. Is it doing nothing more than assigning what's in the member array to the variables?

Comment: That is what deconstructing means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openOrSenior(data) {
    return data.map(([age, handicap]) => (age > 54 && handicap > 7) ? 'Senior' : 'Open');
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                      destructuring
}
```

This is a simple map implementation. The only thing worth mentioning is the destructuring part where `[age, handicap]` first gets assigned to `[18,20]` which means `age` gets assigned to `18` and `handicap` gets assigned to `20`.

Comment: It is as simple as that, huh? I think I misread some part in the documentation, there's a different notation when dealing with arrays compared to dealing with objects, i.e. destructuring with arrays uses [] on the left hand side, and destructuring with objects uses {} on the left hand side. I glossed over using [] with destructuring arrays, and when I saw this it didn't click. Got it now, awesome!